# What is the simplest way to list the files from a local folder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I would like to read a path (not necessarily use a full blown file selector), and list the files in that path and be able to read their contents.

I want it to run on desktop MacOS.

I tried some stuff, but couldn't make it work.

I would appreciate some links, but I would prefer an example, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Standard `dart:io` classes like [`Directory`](https://api.dart.dev/dart-io/Directory-class.html) and [`File`](https://api.dart.dev/dart-io/File-class.html) work in Flutter desktop applications. If you're having issues using them the most likely explanation is that you haven't disabled the [macOS App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox) for your application; a sandboxed application can't read arbitrary parts of the filesystem.

Try removing the sandbox entry from your two entitlements files in `macos/Runner/` and then testing your code again.